# How to calculate Amazon server prices

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gis, ram

I need a server with a lot of RAM, around ~1TB, for a GIS DB, that would be not written to hard disk, because the data is irrelevant after a few seconds. So I do not need a lot of disk space; I wish to hold all data in memory. The write data would be 1% of INSERT'S and 99% of UPDATE's. Write/Read ratio would be 20/1. I have to choose to rent a dedicated server or rent an Amazon service. I'm wondering: how to calculate the price of Amazon services with traffic ~100TB/month.

Comment: This was what I needed:
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might reconsider your configuration, using SSD disk, a really great CPU, and a lot of ram, but 1To of ram is way too much, most system will not handle it. After it's for the price ! It's really expensive, that kind of configuration is 15000$++ a month at OVH for example. So I thinks if you have that kind of problem, the better is to directly call Amazon and ask them for the best configuration and negociate the price.

Comment: Does not exists any calculator script for this purpose?

Comment: Also as a dedicated server i have found this one offer: D7-V1800: 4 x Eight Core 2.20Ghz (E5-4620); 2 x 240GB SSD + 4 x 300GB; 1536GB DDR3 EEC Memory; Unlimited 10Gbps Port / 500Mbps Guaranteed -> £2858.00 per month. This is around 4,5K$, also much under a 15k$+

Comment: You need at least 2 of that kind to have the power of the cloud: high disponibility, and cloud service also include support you will not have to configure all you server, and with that king of configuration (4 disk for exemple) you will need skills if your raid is down.
It's dedicated not cloud

Comment: How said, I do not really need the disks, they are inclusive. And it is not a problem if the server goes down for reboot. The "power of cloud" that i need is a lot of memory space for less money. Is it possible? I do not understand how calculate my case from the pricing site of amazon.